# Has NATO already terminated Art. 5 invoked for 9/11?

Tags: nato, afghanistan

After 9/11, NATO invoked [Art. 5](https://www.nato.int/cps/en/natohq/official_texts_17120.htm) because they considered it an "armed attack" against the USA. The same article states that

> Such measures shall be terminated when the Security Council has taken the measures necessary to restore and maintain international peace and security.

Has this already happened or does NATO believe that the USA is still under "armed attack" from Afghanistan/"terror"? Are there any official statements from NATO regarding the end of Art. 5?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of December 2017, the Security Council continues to produce resolutions that condemn terrorism and authorise (resolutions [2395](https://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=S/RES/2395(2017)) and [2396](https://www.un.org/en/ga/search/view_doc.asp?symbol=S/RES/2396(2017))).

There does not appear to be a resolution that notes the defeat of any terrorist group in the region.

Article 5 was not written in anticipation of a terrorist conflict, instead it expects war with a State actor that could be fought, defeated and forced to surrender in the way that Nazi Germany had been defeated. It uses the mechanism of the UN security council, since that was (and is) the forum through which military action can be authorised. It isn't clear how this part of the treaty would be applied to a non-state actor.

Comment: To load the links on Chrome, remove `https`: There are some issues with the UN's document serving over https which it blocks by default. I've sent them a message, so perhaps they'll fix it.

Comment: @TemporalWolf From what I can tell, that's as much a browser issue as it is a site issue.  The pages are mixing secure and insecure sources, and you (like me) may have settings set to block insecure content when secure content is present.  My Opera browser still mentions blocking insecure content even without the https because the page invariably loads up mixed-security elements (but nothing loads with the https variant).

Comment: @zibadawatimmy Blocking mixed content is the norm now. Sites should be configured to use HTTPS as much as possible. This makes it possible to load external resources without risk of tampering and without giving the end user a false sense of security (where the original page is secured but the external resources, like executable JavaScript, are not).

Comment: So it will probably never end.